# How do you add two series together

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

How do you add the series

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n}}{(z-3)^{n+1}} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(z-3)^{n}}{4^{n+1}}\right)$$
?

is this right?
$$\begin{aligned}
&\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2^{n}}{(z-3)^{n+1}} + \frac{(z-3)^{n}}{4^{n+1}}\right)\\
 =\> & \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(4^{n+1} \cdot 2^{n}) + (z-3)^{n} (z-3)^{n+1}}{(z-3)^{n+1}  4^{n+1}} \right)\\
 =\>& \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(4^{n+1} \cdot 2^{n}) +  (z-3)^{n+1+n}}{(z-3)^{n+1} 4^{n+1}}\right)\\
 =\>& \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(4^{n+1} \cdot 2^{n}) +  (z-3)^{2n+1}}{(z-3)^{n+1} 4^{n+1}}\right)\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Why do you want to combine them in that fashion?

Comment: Just to try and understand how to add power series together.

Comment: Well, one can add the series term by term, which you have in the very first expression.  There is nothing gained here, and actually something lost, by proceeding as in the post.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're doing fine so far. You can do a bit better by noting that $$4^{n+1}=\left(2^2\right)^{n+1}=2^{2(n+1)}=2^{2n+2}$$ and that $$4^{n+1}\cdot(z-3)^{n+1}=\bigl(4(z-3)\bigr)^{n+1}=(4z-12)^{n+1}.$$

You could also distribute the $\frac12$ through, if you like.

I do have to wonder what you gain from combining these two series, though. In combined form, they don't give nearly as much information as readily, in exchange for a little saved space.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n}}{(z-3)^{n+1}} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(z-3)^{n}}{4^{n+1}}\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{2(z-3)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{2}{z-3}\right)  ^n + 
\frac18  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{z-3}{4}\right)  ^n   $$

evaluate the two sums using the formula for geometric series and add the results.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't wrong but if i were you i would write it as Laurent series. $\displaystyle\frac {1}{2}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^n}{(z-3)^{n+1}}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(z-3)^n}{4^{n+1}}\right) = \frac {1}{2}\left(\sum_{n=-1}^{-\infty} \frac{(z-3)^n}{2^{n+1}}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(z-3)^n}{4^{n+1}}\right)$
$\displaystyle = \frac 12 \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n (z-3)^n$

where $a_n := \begin{cases}\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\quad\text{if n<0}\\\frac{1}{4^{n+1}}\quad\text{if }n\geq 0\end{cases}$.

If you want to evaluate the sum i suggest just leaving it as it is.